Installing Qt5 using the online installer
There is no selection of any components 
In the online installer, all components are missing. What could be the reason?
Maybe there's an alternative? Without building from source code.
Windows 11 pro system.
I tried to find and delete all QT configs I could find on the system.

Does the problem persist? sometimes Qt file servers are unreachable
